# Why are read-only nodes called read-only in the case of data store replication?

Tags: serverless, cqrs, database-replication, sharding, transactional-replication

I was going through the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs which says, "If separate read and write databases are used, they must be kept in sync". One obvious benefit I can understand from having separate read replicas is that they can be scaled horizontally. However, I have some doubts:

1. It says, "Updating the database and publishing the event must occur in a single transaction". My understanding is that there is no guarantee that the updated data will be available immediately on the read-only nodes because it depends on when the event will be consumed by the read-only nodes. Did I get it correctly?
2. Data must be first written to read-only nodes before it can be read i.e. write operations are also performed on the read-only nodes. Why are they called read-only nodes? Is it because the write operations are performed on these nodes not directly by the data producer application; but rather by some serverless function (e.g. AWS Lambda or Azure Function) that picks up the event from the topic (e.g. Kafka topic) to which the write-only node has sent the event?
3. Is the data sharded across the read-only nodes or does every read-only node have the complete set of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these have "it depends"-like answers...

1. Yes, usually, although some implementations might choose to (try to) update read models transactionally with the update.  With multiple nodes you're quickly forced to learn the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), though, and so in many CQRS contexts, eventual consistency is just accepted as a feature, as the gains from tolerating it usually significantly outweigh the losses.
   I suspect the bit you quoted anyway refers to transactionally updating the *write* store with publishing the event. Even this can be difficult to achieve, and is one of the problems event sourcing seeks to solve.
2. Yes.  It's trivially obvious - in this context - that data must be written before it can be read, but your apps as consumers of the data see them as read-only.
3. Both are valid outcomes.  Usually this part is less an application concern and is more delegated to the capabilities of your chosen read-model infrastructure (Mongo, Cosmos, Dynamo, etc).

Comment: Great answer! You have explained all the points nicely and clearly. I will keep it open for a couple of days and if I do not get any other answer, I will mark it as an answer.